# How to check if user already saw popup by using cookie in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, popup

I made a popup dialog using jQuery UI. I want to show it to every user (regardless of being registered or not). So, I created two PHP script files (`dynamic.php` for the registered user and `static.php` for non register user).

I have no problem in `dynamic.php` but for `static.php` (creating a cookie to check if the user has already answered or not) it's not working. Here is my code.

```
$cookie = "";
$rnd_cookie="";
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && $_COOKIE['user_id']==$cookie) { 
    echo "this static user already answer<br/>";    
    echo "cookie ".$_COOKIE['user_id']."<br/>";
    echo "check_cookie ".$cookie."<br/>";
} else {                    
    $rnd_cookie = rand()*1000;
    setcookie("user_id",$rnd_cookie,time()+28800);//expire time 8 hrs
    echo "create cookie value: $rnd_cookie<br/>";
    echo "cookie: ".$_COOKIE['user_id']."<br/>";
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['user_id'];

    check();
}
```

I can't get cookie value immediately after setting the cookie like this:

```
setcookie("user_id",$rnd_cookie,time()+28800);//expire time 8 hrs
$cookie = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
```

I have no idea how to check whether the user can see the popup or not with the cookie. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Can't you use Sessions for this?

Comment: No, I want to use only cookie. Is there any way?